# Emacs prevent backups in the form `#<filename>#`

Tags: emacs, elisp

I like to write some Java code to test out the new lisp features that I program. When I do this I open a new buffer and then usually restart emacs. When I `C-x C-c`, emacs wants me to save the file, and if I do not it generates a backup of the form `#<filename>#`. How can I stop this from happening, without disabling the backup of the form `<filename>~`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not backup files; they are auto-save files.  If you do not want Emacs to auto-save buffers then customize option `auto-save-default` to `nil`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Auto Save Control](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html).

Comment: Is there a way to make it still make the file if Emacs crashes?